# Why an Int32 variable can't be assigned to an Int64 variable or vice versa in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, integer, swift5

I could not assign `Int32` `var`/`let` to `Int64` `var`/`let` or vice-versa in Swift. I get a compile time error when I attempt to do so. What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable as Int32, the memory allocated for that variable is 4bytes and for Int64 type variable the memory allocated is 8 bytes.

You can't put 64bytes data into 32 byte data as you can't put 2litres of water into 1 litre bottle.

In order to avoid such problems, swift has strict type checking feature and ensure such problems are not arise in run time.

Comment: So, we must safely cast one type to another using the initializer, keeping in mind the range supported by each type, right ?

Comment: Yes @Kris or else you can directly use Int type so that Swift will do memory management for you to avoid unnecessary run time errors